# PreferenceFragment and backstack with getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I started to change my App to [Material design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html).

I´ve changed my Activity to `ActionBarActivity` and My Theme to AppCompat, to be able to color ActionBar and use AppCompat Navigation drawer.

I´m switching Fragments in my Activity, which are added to backstack throught

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
 .beginTransaction()
 .replace(...)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();
```

I have to use SupportFragmentManager because of AppCompat. Therefore, I have to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from support library.

**Problem:**

I´m also using `PreferenceFragment`, which is not included in support library. And therefore, I can´t add the fragment to backstack.

Error: The method replace(int, Fragment, String) in the Type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the Arguments (int, SettingsFragment, String)

The solution I'm using right now is this [library](https://github.com/Machinarius/PreferenceFragment-Compat). I don't want to use it, because I'm targeting  API 14.

**Is there a way I can use PreferenceFragment with SupportFragmentManager?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, support `FragmentManager` accepts only support `Fragment`s and there is no way you can use fragments from `android.app` package.
BTW, I suggest you to use [this library](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) instead. It has `minSdkVersion` of 7, but it has recent updates and I think it's more stable than the library you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` from preference-compat-v7 support library. These objects can be handled by `SupportFragmentManager`.